# Prevent google from indexing Postback Ajax destination

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, google-index

I have a website example.com where I have a number of pages where comments can be made.  Instead of using submit/postback to post the comments back to the server, I use Ajax but it seems to have created additional pages.

```
http://example.com/page
http://example.com/page/postcomment
```

It has indexed the postcomment page rather than the one without the postcomment.  How can I prevent Google from indexing postback function calls?  Below is the Jquery/Ajax function that I call to submit the comment and what Google then going on to index.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: '/page/postcomment', dataType: "json", 
data: data, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 

success: function () { alert('Thanks for commenting, it will be reviewed and uploaded later.'); }, 

error: function (response) { alert(response.statusText); } }); } } });
```

Comment: [Question on Webmasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/101763/17633)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about Google indexing, not about coding.   This has already been cross-posted to Webmaster StackExchange, which is the correct place for this question.

Comment: Put this question on both in case there was a coding solution but the answer below seems to do the trick.  Google Robot.txt seems to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it is related to SEO. If so, you can create ***robots.txt*** at the root level.

For example,

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /*/postcomment
```

***FYI:*** It will take 24 to 48 hours for Google to index the site again.

Comment: Also ensure the Canonical html tag is dry correctly and both point to the same place.